# How to appnd a line in the files avaialbe in sitest-enabled apache2 in ubuntu using php code?

Tags: php, ubuntu, command

I am trying to append another virtual host entry in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf in ubuntu 16.04 using php. What I want is to add another entry, restart the server and check if it works as normal.  Any ideas or solution will help.

But I could not use shell_exec or exec to handle this objective. I have tried these codes

```
return exec("gedit /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf 2>&1 ");
```

and this one

```
$file = '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf ';
    $message = "test".PHP_EOL;
    return file_put_contents($file, $message, FILE_APPEND);
```